# Let $G=\langle\mu\rangle$ be the subgroup of $S_4$, now compute the coset of $G$ using...?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, permutations, finite-groups

> Let $G= \langle \mu \rangle$ be the subgroup $S_4$ generated by $$\mu =\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
> 2 & 3 & 4 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}.$$
> Compute all the cosets of G containing the permutation $\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
> 4 & 3 & 2 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}.$

$$G=  \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

Coset of G is simply $ga$   $\forall g \in G$

Therefore we would have

- $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
  4 & 3 & 2 & 1
  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
  4 & 3 & 2 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}$
- $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
  4 & 3 & 2 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}=(1 3)(2 3)(4 1)  (4 1)(2 3)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  3 & 2 & 1 & 4\end{pmatrix}$
- $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
  4 & 3 & 2 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}=(1 3) (4 2)  (4 1)(2 3)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  2 & 1 & 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}$
- $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
  4 & 3 & 2 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}= (2 3) (4 3)(4 1)  (4 1)(2 3)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  1 & 4 & 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}$

So I am not $100\%$ sure if I am thinking about this correctly. Please let me know if there are other ways or more clear ways of thinking about this.

I think if $\mu$ as a $90$ degree rotation counter clockwise to a square that has
one of the left top corner, two in the top right corner, 3 on the bottom right corner and 4 on the bottom left corner. Though I don't think this is the right way of thinking about this, especially when applying $a$ to $ga$ (because $a$ would be a $90$ degree rotation clockwise)?

Comment: Your computations for $\mu^2 a$ and $\mu^3 a$ are not correct. you have $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}$ but it should be $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 1 & 4 & 3\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Oh my, I see my mistake now. Wow I really dropped the ball on that one. Thank you.

Comment: @JustinBenfield but isn't $\mu^3 a$ correct? I just re-did the computation and got the same result.

Comment: Yea it looks correct, maybe I didn't notice it was fine earlier? Easy way to see what to correct values *should* be is to note that $G$ inverts the order 1234 to 4321, so it will have the same effect on every element generated by $\mu$ (it will invert the final order that would otherwise have been the result).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Cosets of any group by any subgroup partition the group . . .

> . . . and so each element of the desired cosets of $G$ is in exactly one coset; namely, $G\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Holly smokes. Wow I think I read the question entirely wrong. It said "compute all the cosets of $G$ containing $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
4 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ , what I did was computed $G\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
4 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ Which is not the same thing.......?